flutter unable to decrypt text after hot restart
i am using encrypt package to encrypt and decrypt my plaintext. i have followed the examples in https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt. it encrypts and decrypts successfully until i hot restart my app. after i hot restart, the it returns the following error: Invalid or corrupted pad block. the plaintext are encrypted and uploaded to Firestore and for decryption, it is retrieved from Firestore and decrypted. tia for all inputs
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

// Generate a key and IV for encryption
final Key key = Key.fromUtf8('my 32 length key................');
final IV iv = IV.fromLength(16);

final Encrypter encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));

// Encrypt message
String encryptMessage(String plainTextMessage) {
  final Encrypted encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainTextMessage, iv: iv);
  return encrypted.base64;
}

// Decrypt message
String decryptMessage(String encryptedMessage) {
  final Encrypted encrypted = Encrypted.fromBase64(encryptedMessage);
  final String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
  return decrypted;
}


IV.fromLength() generates a random IV. On restart, most likely a new random IV is generated so that the IV is different for encryption and decryption. Log the IV during encryption and decryption to verify this.

To avoid this, the IV is passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext, usually concatenated: IV|ciphertext (the IV is not secret). On the decrypting side, both parts are to be separated.

Also, don't try to solve the issue with a constant IV. The encrypt package applies the CTR (aka SIC) mode by default (s. here, sec. Modes of operation. In general, the reuse of key/IV pairs is a vulnerability, but with CTR mode this is particularly dangerous (s. here).

Is CTR the same as SIC? i see there's 2 modes in encrypt. Do you also happen to have any recommendations then?

SIC is a synonym for CTR, s. here. The encrypt package supports various modes, in addition to CTR also ECB, CBC, CFBn and OFBn, s. here, sec. Modes of operation. For a general overview and description of the modes, see s. here and regarding their advantages and disadvantages s. e.g. How to choose an AES encryption mode (CBC ECB CTR OCB CFB)?.

Nowadays I would strongly recommend authenticated encryption, e.g. the GCM mode. This is also supported by the encrypt package (even though it is not listed in the general documentation), s. this example. Note that the encrypt package is a high level wrapper over some functionality of the much more powerful PointyCastle library, which can also be used directly.
